# Embedding a chart into a Lotus Notes Email Body

Tags: email, excel, graph, lotus-notes, vba

Thank you to a fellow Stack Overflow user who help me get this chart into an attachment on an email.  It is greatly appreciated.  the next step i have is trying to get it into the actual body of the email as an image or copy.  while the attachment works, the presentation would be much better with it in the body, with nothing to open other than the email.  Anyone have any advice?  I have not heard a lot of good things about trying to do this with Lotus.

```
Sub SendEmail()
  ' setting up various objects
    Dim Maildb As Object
    Dim UserName As String
    Dim MailDbName As String
    Dim MailDoc As Object
    Dim Session As Object
    Dim recipient As String
    Dim ccRecipient As String
    Dim bccRecipient As String
    Dim subject As String
    Dim bodytext As String
    Dim User As String
    Dim Fname As String




    User = Application.UserName

     ' setting up all sending recipients
    recipient = "Someonelse@somewhereelse"
     'ccRecipient =Someoneelse@Somewhereelse.com
     'bccRecipient = ""
    subject = "Week-To-Date GM%"
    bodytext = "" & vbLf & _
               "" & vbLf & _
               "Here is a breakdown of your total GM% for this week.  The graph gives you the GM% by day, with the WTD% displayed as " & vbLf & _
               "individual points on the graph.  We will continue to develop this report for you to provide you with better information."




     ' creating a notes session
    Set Session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
    UserName = Session.UserName
    MailDbName = Left$(UserName, 1) & Right$(UserName, (Len(UserName) - InStr(1, UserName, " "))) & ".nsf"
    Set Maildb = Session.GETDATABASE("", MailDbName)

    If Maildb.IsOpen <> True Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Maildb.OPENMAIL
    End If

    Set MailDoc = Maildb.CreateDocument
    MailDoc.Form = "Memo"

    Fname = Environ$("temp") & "\GM1%.jpeg"

    Sheets("Chart").Shapes("Chart 2").Chart.Export Filename:=Fname, FilterName:="JPEG"

     ' loading the lotus notes e-mail with the inputed data
    With MailDoc
        .SendTo = recipient
         '.copyto = ccRecipient
         '.blindcopyto = bccRecipient
        .subject = subject
        .Attachment.Add Fname
        .Body = bodytext
    End With


     ' saving message (Change to True if you want to save it)
    MailDoc.SaveMessageOnSend = False

       Attachment1 = Worksheets("Chart").Shapes("Chart 2").ChartArea

     ' send e-mail
    MailDoc.PostedDate = Now()
     ' if error in attachment or name of recipients

        Dim rtitem As Object
        Dim object As Object

        Set rtitem = MailDoc.CreateRichTextItem("Attachment1")
        Set object = rtitem.EmbedObject(1454, "", Fname)

    MailDoc.Send 0, recipient

    Kill (Fname)

    Set Maildb = Nothing
    Set MailDoc = Nothing
    Set attachMe = Nothing
    Set Session = Nothing
    Set EmbedObj1 = Nothing

     'Unload Me
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: In regards to the vote.  I have been trying to get this to work for a couple of days.  This includes trying to find an answer on stack overflow.  Sorry I did not specify all the work I've put into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just need to change the 1454 to 1453 to embed an object instead of an attachment.

To get it into the body, though, change the line that creates a rich text item to:

```
Set rtitem = MailDoc.CreateRichTextItem("Body")
```

And if you need to add text to the body of the email you can use

```
rtitem.AppendText("text")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Not in an environment where I can test it right now, but I do appreciate the assist on it!

Comment: I made the recommended adjustments, and it removed the attachments, but did not embed the image.

Comment: Also, as an entirely different way to handle this, you could choose to create the email using the MIME classes.  I've had good luck with that method, and I should've suggested that originally.  Here is a primer on it:  http://www.grange.com.br/blog/40-lotus/499-lotusscript-code-to-embed-a-picture-into-a-notes-richtext-item